# Распарсить List<string>

Tags: c#

В `List<string>` добавляются строки такого вида: `1|Александр|Иванов`

Как каждый текст через разделитель `|` записать в отдельную переменную? Данное чудо нужно реализовать в цикле, т.к таких строк много.

Или же подскажите, пожалуйста, на что можно заменить? Думаю, по описанию понятно, что мне нужно.

Или может можно вообще напрямую реализовать то, что мне нужно? Короче, приведу пример со строкой выше. `1` - это уникальный номер (*ID*), мне нужно по *ID* получить имя и фамилию.

Comment: Я выскажусь в поддержку ответов, которые предлагают ввести класс типа `Person` (и, возможно, `Dictionary` для быстрого поиска). Однако, я предлагаю пойти дальше и вообще убрать `List<string>`. Должна быть коллекция экземпляров `Person`. А для хранения в файле (вот, наверно, откуда у вас строки берутся) эту коллекцию следует сериализовать в JSON или XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringsArray` - тут храните строки

```
for (int x=0; x<stringsArray.Length; x++)
{
    string[] result = stringsArray[x].Split('|');
    // куда вы строки складывать будете я без понятия
    // в данном случае на каждом проходе цикла будете иметь разбитую строку
}
```

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за ответы, этот вариант мне подошел отлично, НО с вариантов выше, я тоже кое-что усвоил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "1|Александр|Иванов",
    "2|Александра|Иванова"
};

var q = from s in list
let parts = s.Split('|')
select new Person
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
    FirstName = parts[1],
    LastName = parts[2]
};

foreach (var i in q)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Id = {i.Id}");
}
```

> мне нужно по ID получить имя и фамилию.

```
var result = q.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
Console.WriteLine($"Имя = {result.FirstName}, Фамилия = {result.LastName}");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<int, Person> ParsePeople(List<string> aLines, List<string> anErrors)
{
  anErrors.Clear();
  Dictionary<int, Person> result = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

  int id;
  string[] delimiters = new string[] { "|" };
  foreach (string line in aLines)
  {
    string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters);
    if (parts.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(parts[0], out id))
    {
      result[id] = new Persion() { ID = id, FirstName = parts[1], LastName = parts[2]};
    }
    else
    {
      anErrors.Add(line);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```